# Express prepend every endpoint with /api/

Tags: node.js, express

I have such endpoints:

```
GET /whoami
POST /login
POST /logout
POST /reset
...
much more
...
```

How to prepend every endpoint with let's say "/api"? So it becomes available at:

```
GET /api/whoami
POST /api/login
POST /api/logout
POST /api/reset
```

Is it possible to write some kind of middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
import * as express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/login', (req,res) => {
   // Your code
});
app.use('/api', router);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](https://www.terlici.com/2014/09/29/express-router.html), to get an understanding of sub routing in Express. You could sub route all the route with /api